# boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden (rights issue or something else)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I am trying to fetch Elastic IPs for in my AWS system, i am not sure whether i am using incorrect code or its the permission issue. Fetching regions is working fine. However, when i try to fetch ip address it gives permission issue:

```
regions = boto.ec2.regions()
for obj in regions:
    print(obj.name)
```

Output:

us-east-1
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2

Trying to fetch IP address

```
address1=boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection()
print(address1.get_all_addresses())
```

Error is given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/code/python_pro/AWS/connection_boto3.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(address1.get_all_addresses())
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\boto\ec2\connection.py", line 1811, in get_all_addresses
    return self.get_list('DescribeAddresses', params, [('item', Address)], verb='POST')
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>UnauthorizedOperation</Code><Message>You are not authorized to perform this operation.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>4fe0918f-f508-4faa-a30f-37bcdb9bd812</RequestID></Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly indicating that you are not authorized to perform the operation. Check your IAM policy/role permissions

`UnauthorizedOperation</Code><Message>You are not authorized to perform this operation.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>4fe0918f-f508-4faa-a30f-37bcdb9bd812</RequestID></Response>`